# Is it possible to make the 'go' and 'golang' tags synonyms?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

In Stack Overflow there is a [go](/questions/tagged/go) tag and a [golang](/questions/tagged/golang) tag. Both are natural tags for the [go programming language](http://golang.org). It wouldn't make sense to merge the tags and get rid of one, can they be made synonymous or equivalent instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on [go](/questions/tagged/go), you should find that there is a [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/synonyms) tab, which shows [golang](/questions/tagged/golang) and [go-language](/questions/tagged/go-language) as synonyms. Try both of those tags - you'll see you end up back at [go](/questions/tagged/go). <strike>This has either already been done, or done in response to this question, I can't tell which :)</strike> if you look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) you can see when tag synonyms were proposed. golang was created jul 16 '10 at 15:51 by Bill the Lizard, as was go-language.

Comment: Searches for the 'go' and 'golang' tags turn up different results. So if its recent then maybe some reindexing would need to occur. Otherwise, not sure what that means.

Comment: @Bill hmmm - if I type `[golang]` into the search box it redirects to go; perhaps there's an issue with [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115670/tag-synonyms-hide-questions-tagged-with-the-synonym-in-searches) - if I type `golang` as you say it searches for the phrase `golang` as opposed to recognising it is a synonym...